# Why is some of the colorization of cells not occurring, and is there a connection between that and the "Cannot perform runtime binding" err msg?

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, nullreferenceexception, excel-interop

I'm getting the following err msg:

[image]

This is occurring in this code:

```
private bool GetContractForDescription(string desc)
{
    int DESCRIPTION_COL_NUM = 2;
    int CONTRACT_COL_NUM = 7;
    bool contractVal = false;

    int rowsUsed = _xlBook.Worksheets["PivotData"].UsedRange.Rows.Count;
    int colsUsed = _xlBook.Worksheets["PivotData"].UsedRange.Columns.Count;
    string colsUsedAsAlpha 
ReportRunnerConstsAndUtils.GetExcelColumnName(colsUsed);
    string endRange = string.Format("{0}{1}", colsUsedAsAlpha, rowsUsed);

    Range sourceData = _xlBook.Worksheets["PivotData"].Range[string.Format("A2:{0}", endRange)];

    // This is blowing up for some reason, so look for more detail on why
    string currentDesc = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= rowsUsed; i++)
        {
            var dynamicCell = (Range)sourceData.Cells[i, DESCRIPTION_COL_NUM];
            currentDesc = dynamicCell.Value2.ToString();
            if (currentDesc.Equals(desc))
            {
                var dynamicContractCell = (Range)sourceData.Cells[i, CONTRACT_COL_NUM];
                contractVal = (bool)dynamicContractCell.Value2;
                break;
            }
        }
        return contractVal;
    }
    catch (Exception  ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("currentDesc is {0}; exception is {1}", currentDesc, ex.Message));
    }
    return false;
}
```

And weirder yet, a range of rows/cols that I colorize under a particular circumstance has a "hole cut out of it" where it is not being colored.

Here is the source data in question (the middle row (156), with the "TRUE" value in the last column, is the key one):

[image]

Here is how that data is rendered on the pivottable (the middle block of data, rows 293-297, being key):

[image]

Here is the code I use to pivotize the source data:

```
private void AddPivotTable()
{
    int FIRST_DESCRIPTION_ROW = 8;
    int LINES_BETWEEN_DESCRIPTION_VALS = 5;

    var pch = _xlBook.PivotCaches();
    int rowsUsed = _xlBook.Worksheets["PivotData"].UsedRange.Rows.Count;
    int colsUsed
_xlBook.Worksheets["PivotData"].UsedRange.Columns.Count;
    string colsUsedAsAlpha
ReportRunnerConstsAndUtils.GetExcelColumnName(colsUsed);
    string endRange = string.Format("{0}{1}", colsUsedAsAlph
rowsUsed);

    Range sourceData
_xlBook.Worksheets["PivotData"].Range[string.Format("A1:{0}", endRange)];

    PivotCache pc = pch.Create(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabas
sourceData);
    PivotTable pvt = pc.CreatePivotTable(_xlPivotTableSheet.Range["A6"
"PivotTable");
    pvt.MergeLabels = true;

    pvt.PivotFields("Description").Orientation
XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
    var monthField = pvt.PivotFields("MonthYr");
    monthField.Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField;
    monthField.NumberFormat = "mmm yyyy";
    monthField.DataRange.Interior.Color
ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.LightBlue);

    pvt.CompactLayoutColumnHeader = "Months";
    pvt.CompactLayoutRowHeader = "Description";

    pvt.AddDataField(pvt.PivotFields("TotalQty"), "Total Packages
XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum).NumberFormat = "###,##0";
    pvt.AddDataField(pvt.PivotFields("TotalSales"), "Total Purchases
XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum).NumberFormat = "$#,##0";
    PivotField avg = pvt.CalculatedFields().Add("Average Price
"=TotalSales/TotalQty", true);
    avg.Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField;

    // TODO: This calculation needs to change (it needs to actually 
made a calculation, rather than just the TotalSales val)
    pvt.CalculatedFields()._Add("PercentOfTotal", "=TotalSales");
    pvt.AddDataField(pvt.PivotFields("PercentOfTotal"), "% of Total
Type.Missing).NumberFormat = "###.##";
    . . .
```

...and here is the code to color the item in question:

```
for (m = 1; m <= dataCnt + 1; m++)
{
    string descVal = cellRng.Value2.ToString();
    bool isContractItem = GetContractForDescription(descVal);
    if (isContractItem)
    {
        mcellRng = _xlPivotTableSheet.Range[
            _xlPivotTableSheet.Cells[rowcnt, 1],
            _xlPivotTableSheet.Cells[rowcnt + 4, _grandTotalsColumn-1]];
        mcellRng.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(CONTRACT_ITEM_COLOR);
        mcellRng.EntireRow.RowHeight = 15;
    }
    . . .
```

I don't see how the colorization code (directly above) can only partially work - as seen in the second screenshot, with the first several cells in the B column being white instead of yellow, as the rest of the range is. It's as if there's 
something "poison" in this data that's preventing it from being colorized.

If I generate fewer columns (by using a different date range to run the report) it runs without the err msg (but still has the "hole" in the range in question).

If I just generate two months, it's fine; but if I try six (the "problem" record exists in either case) the exception is thrown...?!?

### UPDATE

When I comment out the entire while loop, it runs without the error, but of course I then do not get the ContractItems colorized.

The problematic while loop is:

```
while ((cellRng.Value2 != null) && cellRng.Value2.ToString() != "Total Total Packages")
{
    cellRng.RowHeight = 25;
    for (m = 1; m <= pivotTableRowCount; m++)
    {
        string descVal = cellRng.Value2.ToString();
        bool isContractItem = GetContractForDescription(descVal);
        if (isContractItem)
        {
            mcellRng = _xlPivotTableSheet.Range[
                _xlPivotTableSheet.Cells[rowCounter, 1],
                _xlPivotTableSheet.Cells[rowCounter + 4, _grandTotalsColumn - 1]];
            mcellRng.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(CONTRACT_ITEM_COLOR);
            mcellRng.EntireRow.RowHeight = 15;
        }

        rowCounter = rowCounter + LINES_BETWEEN_DESCRIPTION_VALS;
        cellRng = (Range)_xlPivotTableSheet.Cells[rowCounter, 1];
    }
}
```

What in here could be causing that err msg?

It's not the GetContractForDescription() method that is causing the problem, because ignoring it like so:

```
bool isContractItem = false; //GetContractForDescription(descVal);
```

...does not prevent the err msg.

### UPDATE 2

Since my head is mushy from banging it against my wallpaper for so long, I decided to "go back to the coding board" and begin fresh. I now have this code for determining which items are contracted:

```
List<String> contractItemDescs = GetContractItemDescriptions();
MessageBox.Show(contractItemDescs.Count.ToString());
. . .
private List<string> GetContractItemDescriptions()
{
    int FIRST_PIVOTDATA_DATA_ROW = 2;
    int DESCRIPTION_COLUMN = 2;
    int CONTRACT_COLUMN = 7;
    List<string> descriptionsOfContractedItems = new List<string>();
    int pivotDataRowCount = _xlBook.Worksheets["PivotData"].UsedRange.Rows.Count;

    // Loop through the data sheet, adding the Descriptions for all Contract Items to the generic list
    for (int i = FIRST_PIVOTDATA_DATA_ROW; i <= pivotDataRowCount; i++)
    {
        Range contractItemCell = _xlPivotDataSheet.Cells[i, CONTRACT_COLUMN];
        //if (contractItemCell.Value2.ToString() == "TRUE") <= seems to be the same logic as below, but this doesn't work, whereas the below code does...?!?
        if (contractItemCell.Value2.ToString().ToUpper() != "FALSE")
        {
            Range descriptionCell = _xlPivotDataSheet.Cells[i, DESCRIPTION_COLUMN];
            String desc = descriptionCell.Value2.ToString();
            descriptionsOfContractedItems.Add(desc);
        }
    }
    return descriptionsOfContractedItems;
}
```

This is working correctly - the messagebox is showing me the valid count. Note, though, the commented out "if" statement. Using that, I was getting nothing added to the list; with the seeming analogue that I now use, I get the correct/expected behavior, though, I don't know why.

Comment: TL;DR but the easier way to debug should be to comment out the try/catch statements and run in Debug mode to see exactly where the Exception occurs. My guess is this line `contractVal = (bool)dynamicContractCell.Value2;`

Comment: I have been debugging it by stepping through it, but finding exactly which condition is causing the exception is the rub.

Comment: What causes you to suspect that line? The only values it has in the test sheet is "TRUE" and "FALSE"

Comment: explicit casts in general look suspicious to me :] and the error message seems to suggest that the Exception occured after `currentDesc = dynamicCell.Value2.ToString();` and before `return contractVal;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't rightly know why the previous code didn't work, but my guess is that the logic was just generally too discombobulated. I refactored and simplified it (rather than trying to adapt some existing code written by someone else, I started afresh and did it "my way") and it now works just fine. The new code is:

```
private static readonly Color CONTRACT_ITEM_COLOR = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 204);
. . .

private void AddPivotTable()
{
    . . .
    List<String> contractItemDescs = GetContractItemDescriptions();
    ColorizeContractItemBlocks(contractItemDescs);
    . . .
}

private List<string> GetContractItemDescriptions()
{
    int FIRST_PIVOTDATA_DATA_ROW = 2;
    int DESCRIPTION_COLUMN = 2;
    int CONTRACT_COLUMN = 7;
    List<string> descriptionsOfContractedItems = new List<string>();
    int pivotDataRowCount = _xlBook.Worksheets["PivotData"].UsedRange.Rows.Count;

    // Loop through the data sheet, adding the Descriptions for all Contract Items to the generic list
    for (int i = FIRST_PIVOTDATA_DATA_ROW; i <= pivotDataRowCount; i++)
    {
        Range contractItemCell = _xlPivotDataSheet.Cells[i, CONTRACT_COLUMN];
        if (contractItemCell.Value2.ToString().ToUpper() != "FALSE")
        {
            Range descriptionCell = _xlPivotDataSheet.Cells[i, DESCRIPTION_COLUMN];
            String desc = descriptionCell.Value2.ToString();
            descriptionsOfContractedItems.Add(desc);
        }
    }
    return descriptionsOfContractedItems;
}

private void ColorizeContractItemBlocks(List<string> contractItemDescs)
{
    int FIRST_DESCRIPTION_ROW = 8;
    int DESCRIPTION_COL = 1;
    int ROWS_BETWEEN_DESCRIPTIONS = 5;
    int rowsUsed = _xlBook.Worksheets["PivotTable"].UsedRange.Rows.Count;
    int colsUsed = _xlBook.Worksheets["PivotTable"].UsedRange.Columns.Count;
    int currentRowBeingExamined = FIRST_DESCRIPTION_ROW;

    while (currentRowBeingExamined < rowsUsed) 
    {
        Range descriptionCell = _xlPivotTableSheet.Cells[currentRowBeingExamined, DESCRIPTION_COL];
        String desc = descriptionCell.Value2.ToString();
        if (contractItemDescs.Contains(desc))
        {
            Range rangeToColorize = _xlPivotTableSheet.Range[
                _xlPivotTableSheet.Cells[currentRowBeingExamined, 1],
                _xlPivotTableSheet.Cells[currentRowBeingExamined + 4, colsUsed]];
            rangeToColorize.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(CONTRACT_ITEM_COLOR);
        }
        currentRowBeingExamined = currentRowBeingExamined + ROWS_BETWEEN_DESCRIPTIONS;
    }
}
```